# Storing and Reading different types of User Input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Just to give a bit of context, I am trying to program just the simple functions of a Turing Machine.
I am having trouble storing the user input (both strings and integers) into an arraylist and then having the program read through the array and execute a series of commands based on the input.
Below are the letters.

```
    public void  postMenu()
{   
    say( "\tI\timport file"                       );
    say( "\tM\tenter multiple inputs"             );
    say( "\tX\texit program"                      );
    say( "\tS\tenter single input"                );
    say( "" );
    say( "Enter command:" );
}
    public void SecondMenu()
{
    say( "\t?\tprint current cell"                );
    say( "\t=\tassign new symbol to current cell" );
    say( "\tE\terase current cell"                );
    say( "\tL\tmove head to left"                 );
    say( "\tR\tmove head to right"                );
    say( "\tB\trewind to beginning of tape"       );
    say( "\tD\tdump contents of tape"             );
}

public void  say( String  s )
{
    System.out.println( s );
}
```

So for example, the user types in M to input multiple inputs

Ex: 
1 
R 
0 
R 
'blank' 
R
etc.
The program would produce a 'tape' that reads [1, 0, 'blank']
The part I'm having trouble with is this part.

```
    else
        if ( command == 'M')
        {
            say("Type Done to finish inputs");

            String input = getReq.next();
            int binaryinput = getReq.nextInt();

            do {
                List<Object>inputs = new ArrayList<Object>();

                while(!"Done".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                    inputs.add(Integer.parseInt(input));

                    input=getReq.next();
                    if(inputs.isEmpty())
                        return;
                }
            } while (binaryinput == 0 && binaryinput == 1 && input == " ");
```

Right now, if I begin inputting letters, I get an error message. 
For the user inputs:
* Integers cannot be numbers other than binary numbers
(I'm not quite sure if a 'blank' input would be categorized as a string or int.)

- If anything other than binary is entered, it will return an error message stating input is invalid and ask for correct input.
- Letters can also be entered so that the program will move around the tape.
- typing "Done" will end inputs.

In short, I need to be able to store both binary integers and strings (letters and Done) as objects into an arraylist (if there is an easier way to store, please include it) and have the program read said user input array and execute commands based on what letters it reads.

Comment: your while doesn't make sense, you will never have a condition where binaryinput == 0 && binaryinput == 1,  perhaps you wanted to use an ||?

Comment: also when comparing Strings use .equals, in that same while you are using ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing too much with your whiles and you are also re-initializing a new arraylist each time which isn't what I think you want. From what I understand, you want to only add 1's or 0's and letters to your array list?

```
    say("Type Done to Finish Inputs");
    String input = "";
    Integer binaryinput;
    List<Object>inputs = new ArrayList<Object>();

    do {
        input = getReq.nextLine();
        //check for binary
        if(input.matches("\\d"))
        {
            binaryinput = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(binaryinput == 1 || binaryinput == 0)
                inputs.add(binaryinput);
        }
        //check for a single character
        else
        {
            if(input.length() == 1)
                inputs.add(input);  
        }
    } while (!input.equals("done"));
```

Example of Above code

```
Type Done to Finish Inputs
1
6
2
3
4
1
0
0
1
a
b
c
d
fg
done
```

inputs contains the following

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, a, b, c, d]
```